# iphone : How to capitalize the first character of my textfield?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

In my iPhone app, I want to capitalize the first character in my UITextField's text.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simple:

```
NSString *text = [textField text];
NSString *capitalized = [[[text substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString] stringByAppendingString:[text substringFromIndex:1]];

NSLog(@"%@ uppercased is %@", text, capitalized);
```

Comment: Do not forget to apply condition when the string is empty, otherwise the function ends with a fatal error: return [string length] > 0 ? THE_FUNCTION_ABOVE : string;

Answer (score 15):

In Interface Builder (or IB integrated into Xcode 4), if you click on UITextField you can set the text and keyboard behaviour.

[image: Xcode 4 IB]

Answer (score 4):

NSString *capitalizedString = [textField.text capitalizedString];

Comment: That will capitalize the first letter of each word, e.g. `hello world` will become `Hello World`.

Answer (score 1):

here I'm giving a suggestion you try with is . I hope it will be helpful for you.

Go in xib, select textfield then in attribute inspector you got capitalization just select words option

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up the text field in a nib file, select the nib you will see various 'Text Input Traits' in the Text Field Attributes - the first one in the list deals with capitalisation.

see rjstelling's answer.....

Answer (score 0):

Set the Capitalization drop down under textfield attributes to Sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tanking it separate and capitalizing, try this.
Simple 1 line code.

```
NSString *text = [textField text];
NSString *capText = [text capitalizedString]; // capitalizes only first alphabet.
```